# Modification of the screen when releasing AP Documents 2022R2

Tags: customization, acumatica, acumatica-kb

​
Hi guys, I am using AP bulk release, I am inserting an existing document line and at the same time creating a new credit adjustment.

however, you are not inserting the credit adjustment detail, just the header.

Here is my code.

```html
namespace PX.Objects.AP
{
    public class APDocumentRelease_Extension : PXGraphExtension<APDocumentRelease>
    {
        public class APReleaseProcessNewExt : PXGraphExtension<APReleaseProcess>
        {
            public delegate List<APRegister> ReleaseDocProcDel(JournalEntry je, ref APRegister doc, PXResult<APInvoice, CurrencyInfo, Terms, Vendor> res, bool isPrebooking, out List<INRegister> inDocs);
            [PXOverride]
            public virtual List<APRegister> ReleaseDocProc(JournalEntry je, APRegister doc, bool isPrebooking, out List<INRegister> inDocs)
            {
                List<APRegister> ret = null;
                inDocs = null;

                if (doc.CreatedByScreenID == "AP501000" || doc.LastModifiedByScreenID == "AP501000")           
                {
                    APInvoice api = Base.APInvoice_DocType_RefNbr.Current;
                    CurrencyInfo curren = (CurrencyInfo)PXSelect<CurrencyInfo, Where<CurrencyInfo.curyInfoID, Equal<Current<APInvoice.curyInfoID>>>>.Select(Base, doc.CuryInfoID);
                    var apiExt = api.GetExtension<XTAPInvoice>();
                    TaxRev trRow = PXSelectJoin<TaxRev,
                                          InnerJoin<xtb08Sunat, On<xtb08Sunat.taxCD, Equal<TaxRev.taxID>>>,
                                          Where<xtb08Sunat.tGdsSvcsCD, Equal<Required<xtb08Sunat.tGdsSvcsCD>>>>.Select(Base, apiExt.TBienServ);
                        APPayment aPInvoice = Base.APPayment_DocType_RefNbr.Current;
                        decimal tipocambio = curren.CuryMultDiv == "M" ? (decimal)curren.CuryRate : (decimal)curren.RecipRate;
                        decimal p_AmtDetrac = 0;
                        decimal CuryLineAmt = 0;
                        using (PXTransactionScope ts = new PXTransactionScope())
                        {
                            APInvoiceEntry graph = PXGraph.CreateInstance<APInvoiceEntry>();

                            if (doc != null && doc.Released == true && doc.DocType == APDocType.Invoice &&
                                    doc != null && item != null && doc.LastModifiedByScreenID == "AP501000" && doc.Hold == false && apiExt.Detraccion == true)
                            {
                                #region Create detraction record in the APtran table
                                APTran row = ViewAPTran.Insert();
                                row.TranDesc = "Detraccion";
                                row.CuryLineAmt = api.CuryID == "USD" ? Math.Round((decimal)((api.CuryDocBal) * (trRow.TaxRate / 100)) * -1, 2) : Math.Round((decimal)((api.CuryDocBal) * (trRow.TaxRate / 100)) * -1 * tipocambio, 0);
                                Base.APTran_TranType_RefNbr.SetValueExt<APTran.curyLineAmt>(row, row.CuryLineAmt);
                                CuryLineAmt = (decimal)row.CuryLineAmt;
                                row.AccountID = item.AccountID;
                                row.TaxCategoryID = null;
                                row.Released = true;
                                row.SubID = tax.SalesTaxSubID;
                                row.UnitCost = 0m;
                                Base.APTran_TranType_RefNbr.Current.GetExtension<APTranExt>().UsrTipoTransaccion = "AFEC3";
                                ViewAPTran.Update(row);
                                ViewAPTran.Cache.Persist(PXDBOperation.Insert);
                                #endregion
                                #region Crear Detraccion en la tabla xAcDetrac
                                xAcDetrac xad = detracInv.Select(api.DocType, api.RefNbr);
                                if (xad == null)
                                {
                                    p_AmtDetrac = api.CuryID == "USD" ? Math.Round((decimal)((api.CuryDocBal) * (trRow.TaxRate / 100)) * -1, 2) * tipocambio : Math.Round((decimal)((api.CuryDocBal) * (trRow.TaxRate / 100)) * -1, 2);
                                    xAcDetrac xa = ViewxAcDetrac.Insert();
                                    xa.DocType = api.DocType;
                                    xa.RefNbr = api.RefNbr;
                                    xa.BatchAutoNbr = "";
                                    xa.DocAmt = Math.Round(p_AmtDetrac * -1, 0);
                                    xa.Status = "DR";
                                    xa.TranDate = api.DocDate;
                                    ViewxAcDetrac.Update(xa);
                                    ViewxAcDetrac.Cache.Persist(xa, PXDBOperation.Insert);
                                    //ViewxAcDetrac.Cache.Persist(xa, PXDBOperation.Update);
                                }

                                #endregion
                                #region Modifying APInvoice Values ​​- INV
                                APRegister xapreg = doc;
                                APRegister apreg = PXSelect<APRegister,
                                    Where<APRegister.refNbr,
                                    Equal<Required<APRegister.refNbr>>,
                                    And<APRegister.docType, Equal<Required<APRegister.docType>>>>>.Select(Base, xapreg.RefNbr, xapreg.DocType);
                                APInvoice apin = Base.APInvoice_DocType_RefNbr.Current;
                                apin.CuryLineTotal = apin.CuryLineTotal - (apin.CuryID == "USD" ?
                                    Math.Round((decimal)((apin.CuryDocBal) * (trRow.TaxRate / 100)), 2) :
                                    Math.Round((decimal)((apin.CuryDocBal) * (trRow.TaxRate / 100)) * tipocambio, 0));
                                apreg.CuryDocBal = apreg.CuryDocBal - (apin.CuryID == "USD" ?
                                    Math.Round((decimal)((apin.CuryDocBal) * (trRow.TaxRate / 100)), 2) :
                                    Math.Round((decimal)((apin.CuryDocBal) * (trRow.TaxRate / 100)) * tipocambio, 0));
                                apreg.CuryOrigDocAmt = apreg.CuryOrigDocAmt - (apin.CuryID == "USD" ?
                                    Math.Round((decimal)((apin.CuryDocBal) * (trRow.TaxRate / 100)), 2) :
                                    Math.Round((decimal)((apin.CuryDocBal) * (trRow.TaxRate / 100)) * tipocambio, 0));
                                apreg.DocBal = apin.CuryID == "USD" ?
                                    Math.Round((decimal)apreg.CuryDocBal * tipocambio, 2) :
                                    Math.Round((decimal)apreg.CuryDocBal, 2);
                                apreg.NoteID = apin.NoteID;
                                graph.Caches[typeof(APRegister)].Update(apreg);
                                graph.Caches[typeof(APRegister)].Persist(PXDBOperation.Update);
                                #endregion
                                #region Create Record in CurrencyInfo Table
                                CurrencyInfo info1 = ViewCurrencyInfo.Insert();
                                info1.CuryID = "PEN";
                                info1.CuryRateTypeID = "VENTA";
                                info1.CuryEffDate = DateTime.Today;
                                info1.CuryMultDiv = "M";
                                info1.CuryRate = 1;
                                info1.BaseCuryID = "PEN";
                                info1.RecipRate = 1;
                                info1.BaseCalc = true;
                                ViewCurrencyInfo.Update(info1);
                                ViewCurrencyInfo.Cache.Persist(PXDBOperation.Insert);
                                #endregion
                                #region New document header, credit adjustment
                                APInvoiceEntry docgraph = PXGraph.CreateInstance<APInvoiceEntry>();
                                APInvoice xdoc = (APInvoice)api;
                                APInvoice invoice = PXCache<APInvoice>.CreateCopy(xdoc);

                                invoice.DocType = APDocType.CreditAdj;
                                invoice.RefNbr = null;
                                invoice.DocDesc = "Detracci\u00F3n del IGV";
                                invoice.CuryLineTotal = Math.Round(p_AmtDetrac * -1, 0);
                                invoice.CuryDiscTot = 0;
                                invoice.CuryVatTaxableTotal = 0;
                                invoice.CuryVatExemptTotal = 0;
                                invoice.CuryTaxTotal = 0;
                                invoice.CuryOrigWhTaxAmt = 0;
                                invoice.CuryDocBal = Math.Round(p_AmtDetrac * -1, 0);
                                invoice.CuryRoundDiff = 0;
                                invoice.CuryOrigDocAmt = Math.Round(p_AmtDetrac * -1, 0);
                                invoice.CuryOrigDiscAmt = 0;
                                invoice.CuryInfoID = ViewCurrencyInfo.Current.CuryInfoID;
                                invoice.CuryID = ViewCurrencyInfo.Current.CuryID;
                                invoice.PaySel = true;
                                invoice.IsTaxPosted = false;
                                invoice.IsTaxValid = false;
                                invoice.CuryVatTaxableTotal = 0m;
                                invoice.CuryVatExemptTotal = 0m;
                                invoice.PendingPPD = false;
                                invoice.NoteID = null;
                                invoice = docgraph.Document.Insert(invoice);
                                XTDETSetup xtSetup = PXSelect<XTDETSetup>.Select(Base);

                                if (xtSetup != null)
                                {
                                    invoice.PayTypeID = xtSetup.PaymentMethodID;
                                }

                                BAccount2 bAccount2 = PXSelectJoin<BAccount2, LeftJoin<Branch, On<Branch.bAccountID, Equal<BAccount2.bAccountID>>>,
                                    Where<Branch.branchID, Equal<Required<Branch.branchID>>>>.Select(Base, PXAccess.GetBranchID());

                                if (bAccount2 != null)
                                {
                                    var bAccountExt = bAccount2.GetExtension<BAccountExt>();

                                    if (bAccountExt != null && bAccountExt.UsrCashAccountCD != null)
                                    {
                                        CashAccount Cash = PXSelect<CashAccount, Where<CashAccount.cashAccountCD, In<Required<CashAccount.cashAccountCD>>>>.Select(Base, bAccountExt.UsrCashAccountCD);
                                        if (Cash != null)
                                        {
                                            invoice.PayAccountID = Cash.CashAccountID;
                                        }
                                    }
                                }

                                if (doc.IsChildRetainageDocument())
                                {
                                    invoice.OrigDocType = doc.OrigDocType;
                                    invoice.OrigRefNbr = doc.OrigRefNbr;
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    invoice.OrigDocType = doc.DocType;
                                    invoice.OrigRefNbr = doc.RefNbr;
                                }

                                XTAPInvoice xtapi = PXCache<APInvoice>.GetExtension<XTAPInvoice>(invoice);
                                xtb04Sunat sunat = PXSelect<xtb04Sunat, Where<xtb04Sunat.codigo, Equal<Required<xtb04Sunat.codigo>>>>.Select(Base, "D1");
                                if (sunat != null)
                                {
                                    NumberingSequence sequence = PXSelect<NumberingSequence,
                                                                         Where<NumberingSequence.numberingID, Equal<Required<NumberingSequence.numberingID>>>>.Select(Base, sunat.NroSecuencia);
                                    if (sequence != null)
                                    {
                                        var secu = PEFEHelper.NextSecuenceNumber(sequence);
                                        string[] sepa = secu.Split('-');
                                        var serie = sepa[0];
                                        var Nrodocumento = sepa[1];
                                        xtapi.Serie = serie;
                                        xtapi.NroDocumento = Nrodocumento;
                                        xtapi.TBienServ = "000";
                                        xtapi.TDocSunat = sunat.Codigo;
                                        xtapi.Detraccion = false;
                                    }
                                }
                                /*Modificado Fin*/
                                if (tDETSetup.APAccountID != null)
                                {
                                    invoice.APAccountID = tDETSetup.APAccountID;
                                }
                                docgraph.Document.Update(invoice);
                                #endregion
                                #region New document detail, credit adjustment
                                APTran xtran = PXSelect<APTran,
                                Where<APTran.tranType,
                                Equal<Required<APTran.tranType>>, And<APTran.refNbr, Equal<Required<APTran.refNbr>>,
                                And<APTran.tranDesc, Equal<Required<APTran.tranDesc>>>>>>.Select(Base, api.DocType, api.RefNbr, "Detraccion");
                                APTran tran = PXCache<APTran>.CreateCopy(xtran);
                                if (xtran != null)
                                {
                                    APTran tranx = new APTran();
                                    tranx.TranType = invoice.DocType;
                                    tranx.RefNbr = invoice.RefNbr;
                                    var extnew = tran.GetExtension<APTranExt>();
                                    tranx.CuryLineAmt = Math.Round(p_AmtDetrac * -1, 0);
                                    tranx.CuryTranAmt = Math.Round(p_AmtDetrac * -1, 0);
                                    tranx.TranID = null;
                                    tranx.DrCr = "D";
                                    tranx.Released = true;
                                    tranx.CuryInfoID = invoice.CuryInfoID;
                                    tranx.PPVDocType = null;
                                    tranx.PPVRefNbr = null;
                                    extnew.UsrTipoTransaccion = "AFEC3";
                                    docgraph.Transactions.Update(tranx);
                                }
                                #endregion
                                docgraph.Save.Press();
                            }
                            ts.Complete(Base);
                        }
                }
                return ret;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is the result of the insertion, new line and the modification of amounts, but the total detail does not decrease.
Can you tell me that I'm failing?

Here is the document that I am going to create on a new line.

Step 1
[image]

Step 2
[image]

AP release and result.

Step 3

[image]

Step 4

[image]

Credit Adjustment Result

the document header, I created it, but the detail has not been created.

step 5

[image]

I hope I was clear with my request.

I will be very grateful, since I am suffering too much, the version is 2022R2

Answer (score 0):

Be sure to call ViewAPTran.Update(row) after you set row values. When the AP Tran View's Update() method runs that is where the header fields you are showing update to the correct values.